# How to prevent multiple entries for PromptDialog.Number

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-bot-service

I am using PromptDialog.Number method in a bot framework dialog class like this:

```
PromptDialog.Number(context, ResumeAfterClarification, prompt, min:1, max:3, retry:retryText);
```

This works fine for most part. If a user enters a number that is not between 1 and 3, retryText is displayed and the user has to retry. However, if a user enters numbers separated by commas this is accepted (e.g. 1, 2, 3). The first number is passed to resume method, everything else is ignored.

How can I prevent this? It would make sense that any invalid entry (i.e. any entry that is not a single number between min and max) should be rejected.

Am I missing something here? Can this method accept multiple entries? How are they passed to resume method in a single int64 parameter? I really want to disable this.

Comment: Have you tried creating your own PromptInt64 Dialog with Options where you override the PromptRecognizer (and specifically RecognizeNumber)? All the source code to this library is available on github so it shouldn't be hard to figure out.

Comment: No, didn't try that (yet). Still trying to use it as is without customizing it. What I need is fairly vanilla stuff, I just need user to enter a valid number. Not sure if I am using it incorrectly or if this is a bug?

Comment: It may even be possible just by providing your own localized NumberExpression resource. Currently it's a reg-ex that will match anything anywhere in the field that happens to be a number. If you want to change it so the whole expression must be number, it would need to be something like ^[+-]?\d*\.?\d+$" (untested, and wouldn't work if you typed, e.g, just 1. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Dylan Nicholson in comments, you can inherit PromptInt64 and use a custom TryParse method:

```
[Serializable]
public class CustomPromptInt64 : PromptInt64
{
    public CustomPromptInt64(string prompt, string retry, int attempts, long? min = null, long? max = null) 
            : base(prompt, retry, attempts, null, min, max)
    {
    }

    protected override bool TryParse(IMessageActivity message, out long result)
    {
        if(Int64.TryParse(message.Text, out result))
        {
            return (result >= this.Min && result <= this.Max);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And use the CustomPromptInt64 in a dialog:

```
    public Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

   private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {

        var child = new CustomPromptInt64("Number between 1 and 3", "Please try again", 3, min: 1, max: 3);
        context.Call<long>(child, ResumeAfterClarification);
    }

    private async Task ResumeAfterClarification(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<long> result)
    {
        var number = await result;
        context.Done(true);
    }
```